# How to display logged user name in a React application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to display logged in `username` and `user profile` in my React app using TypeScript:

```js
{window.user_image ? (
    <img src={window.user_image}/>
  ):(
    <UserAvatar/>
)}
    
<h3>{window.display_name}</h3>
```

But I am getting the following errors:

> Property 'user_image' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis

> Property 'display_name' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis

How can I display the logged in user name in a TypeScript file, e.g. `info.tsx`

Comment: Where are your user details defined? Could you post some details about how you get the user details and what you do with them afterwards? Then we can make sure that they are getting passed to your react component 

Comment: I have not defined user details anywhere.  I just want to know if I can display the logged in user name using window.display_name. If not , then what is the alternative approach for this.

Comment: Reading from the window in a React component is fine (though the preferred way would be to pass the data as a prop to your component). The error you are seeing is because nothing has put `display_name` on the window object. That's the code I refer to when I ask for user  details. Unfortunately there isn't enough information about how are getting the logged in user information, or how the code snippet you shared relates to the rest of your application, so I don't think it's possible for me to answer this question. If you provide more info, I'm glad to take a look!

Comment: An alternative would be to get that image into `localStorage`, have you tried that..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{window.["user_image"] ? (
    <img src={window.["user_image"]}/>
  ):(
    <UserAvatar/>
)}
    
<h3>{window.["user_image"]}</h3>
```

This solved my problem